# sql query works in azure data studio but returns nothing via vs code

Tags: sql, visual-studio-code

I have the following SQL query that returns a few rows when I try in Azure Data Studio:

```
 SELECT 
     A.ReportRefreshDate, COUNT(ActivityName) AS TotalActivity, 
     ActivityName as ActivityType
 FROM
     WidgetActivity A
 INNER JOIN 
     WidgetUsers ON LOWER(WidgetUsers.UserPrincipalName) = LOWER(A.UserId)
 WHERE 
     A.TMID = 4
     AND WidgetUsers.Branch = '52'
     AND A.ReportRefreshDate BETWEEN DATEADD(DD, -300, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE() 
     AND A.ActivityName IN ('Action1', 'Action2')
 GROUP BY
     A.ActivityName, A.ReportRefreshDate
```

This returns a few rows like this:

```
ReportRefreshDate         TotalActivity ActivityType
-----------------------------------------------------
2022-05-16 07:18:06.000   9             Action1
2022-05-16 07:18:06.000   3             Action2
```

But when I try this in VS Code, it returns an empty result set.

Here's the code snippet:

```
Console.WriteLine(activityFilter);

activityByActivityType = conn.Query<WidgetActivityDetailsByActivityTypes>(
                @"
                SELECT A.ReportRefreshDate, COUNT(ActivityName) AS TotalActivityCount, ActivityName AS ActivityType
                FROM WidgetActivity A
                INNER JOIN WidgetUsers 
                    ON LOWER(WidgetUsers.UserPrincipalName) = LOWER(A.UserId)
                WHERE 
                    A.TMID = @TM
                    AND WidgetUsers.Branch = @Branch
                    AND A.ReportRefreshDate BETWEEN DATEADD(DD, -@RefreshDate, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE() 
                    AND A.ActivityName IN (@ActivityList)
                GROUP BY A.ActivityName, A.ReportRefreshDate
                ",
                new { Branch=branchId, TM = tmid, RefreshDate = dateRange, ActivityList = activityFilter}).ToList();
        }

        return activityByActivityType;
```

I think the problem is related to the `@ActivityList` variable because when I remove that AND clause, a bunch of data is returned.

The `Console.Writeline` on `activityFilter` returns this:

```
 'Activity1', 'Activity2'
```

which looks correct to me.

I'm sure it's something simple I've missed but I can't see it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the sql to look like this:

```
activityByActivityType = conn.Query<WidgetActivityDetailsByActivityTypes>(
                $@"
                SELECT A.ReportRefreshDate, COUNT(ActivityName) AS TotalActivityCount, ActivityName AS ActivityType
                FROM WidgetActivity A
                INNER JOIN WidgetUsers 
                    ON LOWER(WidgetUsers.UserPrincipalName) = LOWER(A.UserId)
                WHERE 
                    A.TMID = @TM
                    AND WidgetUsers.Branch = @Branch
                    AND A.ReportRefreshDate BETWEEN DATEADD(DD, -@RefreshDate, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE() 
                    AND A.ActivityName IN ({activityFilter})
                GROUP BY A.ActivityName, A.ReportRefreshDate
                ",
                new { Branch=branchId, TM = tmid, RefreshDate = dateRange}).ToList();
        }
```